# What are the examples of a high noise enviorment?

Tags: integrated-circuit, noise

I was reading about the noise margin of different gates and ICs and I came to know about the fact that all the ICs has certain noise margin and in that limit the ICs can function properly. So my question is that what are the practical example of some very high noise places where we need to be careful while using gates(or maybe we would need some EMI shields).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is requesting a list, and our tour puts "Questions with too many possible answers or that would require an extremely long answer" in the "don't ask" category

Comment: Long list. But a common source of noise are high currents being switched, either in your device, or a nearby device.

Answer (score 2):

"God is in the details." It depends on the nature of the "noise", and how it's coupled. A poorly-designed layout in an otherwise quiet environment may be very noisy. Strategically adding ground return connections may help. More rarely, strategically subtracting ground return connections may help. Choosing slower logic may help. Choosing faster logic may help. There's no substitute for detailed reasoning together with experience and empirical testing here.